# How do I limit the number of significant digits to *not more* than something with str.format() or f-strings?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I can do something like

```
'Correct answers: {:.2f}'.format(value)
```

For value of 3.141592, this will return 3.14 as desired. However for value of 0 it will return 0.00, as expected but not as desired. I would like to see "0" in this case. Is it possible?

Comment: what should 1.1 be represented by?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, valid question: '1.1'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
'Correct answers: {}'.format(round(5.666666, 2))
'Correct answers: {}'.format(round(5.6, 2))
'Correct answers: {}'.format(round(5, 2))
'Correct answers: {}'.format(round(0, 2))
```

Output:

```
Correct answers: 5.67
Correct answers: 5.6
Correct answers: 5
Correct answers: 0
```